# On Inequivalent Representations

Tags: mathematical-physics, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, quantum-field-theory

Kronz and Lupher in their article, "Unitarily Inequivalent Representations in Algebraic Quantum Theory" say:

> "Fock representations accommodate systems having infinite degrees of freedom; but they do not accommodate systems having an infinite number of particles (or subsystems)."

Then, they add:

> "If the system is a finite-particle system, then all representations are unitarily equivalent—i.e., for any pair there is a unitary operator that transforms one into the other."

It contradicts, it seems, with writings of other physicists in which the inequivalence of some Fock spaces is shown. For example, Umezawa's book, Thermo Fields Dynamics and Condensed States (Ch. 2.4), and Blasone et al's book, Quantum Field Theory and its Macroscopic Manifestations (Ch. 2).

Where is the problem?

Kronz and Lupher's paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10773-005-4683-0

Comment: It would help a lot if you phrase this in mathematical terms. It is not clear to me what the representations are of, for instance.

Comment: The context is algebraic quantum field theory. Representation is of a C*-algebra.

Comment: Yes, that's obvious. The question is **which** C$^*$-algebra.

Comment: The C*-algebra which GNS construction is based on.

Comment: The GNS construction can be applied to any C$^*$-algebra, and the C$^*$-algebra one obtains may or may not be isomorphic with the original one. You are still not saying which C$^*$-algebra you are talking about. To say a phrase like "all representations are unitarily equivalent" one needs to know which algebra one is talking about. The second phrase seems to be talking about $M_n(\mathbb C)$, while I had no idea what the first sentence is saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first quotation states something incorrect. It is correct that Fock representations accommodate systems having infinite degrees of freedom. Moreover, normal states of the algebra are convex combinations of finite-particle vector states: normal states are interpreted as the states with a finite number of particles. However, the class of physical states is not identical with the class of normal states. The condition suggested by a Haag and other people is local normality, i.e. the restriction of a physically admissible state to any local algebra should be normal. Hence, *local* subsystems have a finite number of particles. As Bratteli and Robinson explain, however, a locally normal state can be used to describe an infinite number of particles for which the overall density is finite (*Operator Algebras and Quantum Statistical Mechanics 2* p.26)
2. As for the second quotation it refers to systems of finite degrees of freedom. The Stone- von Neumann theorem identifies all regular states of the CCR-algebra with the locally normal states in the Fock representation of that algebra. This fact leads to the unitary equivalence of all regular representations of the CCR-algebra.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Regarding the second qoute, a system may be a finite- particle system, but has infinite degrees of freedom. So, the Stone- von Neumann theorem fails. Concerning the first point, physicists take the system to be finite-particle to guarantee the separability of the Hilbert space.

Comment: You are right that if you have infinite degrees of freedom, i.e. and infinite pre-Hilbert space on which you define the CCR or CAR algebra, Stone-von Neumann theorem does not apply - even if in the actual state the system has a finite number of particles (2nd quote). However, I do not see the connection between finite particles and the separability of the Hilbert space. The assumption of finite particles has to do with the state of the system (normal state) not with the Fock space.